# Shell script to kill a process in specific time with process name and time as input

Tags: linux, bash, kill-process

I need a shell script to kill a particular running process after a specific time by getting the process name and time as input.

I'm using centos machine i've tried the script but couldn't complete on killing the process on particular timing.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'Process: ' name 
read -p 'Timecontrol: ' time

ps -ef | grep $name | awk '{print $5}'
pkill -9 "$name"
```

the expected output to be kill the process in specific time which will be given as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- With this script you can kill the running process at a specific time by giving the process name and the time.
  [Note: The input for time must be in seconds only, i.e 120 for 2 minutes]

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG=/tmp/kill.log
EXIT_ON_KILL=true
read -p 'Process: ' name
read -p 'killat: ' time

PID=$(ps -ef | grep $name | awk '{print $2}')
ps -ef | grep $name | awk '{print $2}' &>>$LOG

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo -e "\n The process details "
  ps -p $PID 
  else
    echo -e "\nInvalid Process Name" 
  fi

current=$(date +"%T")
killat=$(date -d "+"$time" seconds" "+%T")
echo -e "\nCurrent time $current \nThe time target is $killat"

while : 
do
current=$(date +"%T")
echo $current  

  if [ "${killat}" == "${current}" ]
  then   
    kill -9 $PID   &>>$LOG
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Process $name have been successfully killed"  
        if [ $EXIT_ON_KILL == true ];then
        exit 0
        fi
    else
        echo -e "\nFailed to Kill process $name" 
        echo -e "\nMay be Invalid Process Name" 
        exit 1
    fi

  fi
sleep 2
done
```

### Sample Input:

```
Process: xxxx
Killat: 120
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use a cron job to terminate the process in specific date and time.
- If you have to use a script:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    read -p 'Process: ' name
    read -p 'Timecontrol: ' timecontrol
    while :
    do
      now="$(date --date="$(date +%H:%M)" +%s)"
      x="$(date --date="$timecontrol" +%s)"
      if [ $now == $x ]
      then
        ps -ef | grep $name | awk '{print $5}'
      fi
    done
```

Note:

- Remove `#` if you plan to run this script forever.

Answer (score 0):

The script will not kill the process at that particular time which you want to give it as an input as the script will run and die it will not wait for a specific time.

You can tickle this in two ways.

- Loop but again it will run in the foreground
- Cronjob

```
    #!/bin/bash
    EXIT_ON_KILL=true
    read -p 'Process: ' name
    read -p 'Timecontrol: ' timecontrol        
    while :
    do
    current_time=$(date +"%T")
    echo $current_time "control "
    current_time=$(echo $current_time | cut -d':' -f1-2)    
      if [ "${timecontrol}" == "${current_time}" ]
      then
        echo "killing process"
        kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep $name | awk '{print $2}')
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Process killed having name $name and having $pid"
            if [ $EXIT_ON_KILL == true ];then
            exit 0
            fi
        else
            echo "Failed to Kill process having name $name"
            exit 1
        fi

      fi
    sleep 2
    done
```

`awk '{print $2}'` this return `PID` in ubuntu, you have to check-in Centos if it returns `PID` if not then change it to `awk '{print $5}'`

So you can run with

```
./kill_process.sh
Process: node
Timecontrol: 00:21
```

With Cron job, you do not need to pass time, just pass the name of the process and the script will run on the specified time and will kill the process.

```
#!/bin/bash
EXIT_ON_KILL=true
p_name=$1
kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep $p_name | awk '{print $2}')
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Process killed having name $p_name and having $pid"
        if [ $EXIT_ON_KILL == true ];then
        exit 0
        fi
  else
        echo "Failed to Kill process having name $p_name"
        exit 1
  fi
```

[Create-cron-job-on-CentOS](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1339424625-Create-cron-job-on-CentOS)

`0 0 * * * /path_to_script/kill_process.sh node`

This will kill process every-day-at-midnight